# How do I use a SSH tunnel as a alternative to port forwarding?

Tags: debian, windows, port-forwarding

I want to use SSH as a alternative to port forwarding to use my RDP server from the outside as my ISP's router does not allow port forwarding. Here's what I have in mind:

```
A - client connecting to the RDP server
B - server
C - device running the RDP server
```

A wants to connect to C. Directly connecting to C is impossible, so all the traffic has to flow through B.

Example:
A sends a packet containing "Hello world!". C is supposed to respond with "Test OK!".The IP of A is 255.255.255.255 The IP of B is 1.2.3.4. The IP of C is 4.5.6.7.
So, 255.255.255.255 opens a socket to 1.2.3.4. A sends "Hello world!". B forwards the package to C. C responds with "Test OK!" and sends it back to B. B sends it back to A.
I would like to do something like this with a RDP server.

B runs Debian 8, and C runs Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You do not state what OS your client, A, runs in your example. I'll assume there is some sort of command line ssh client available. Then, you can use

```
 you@A $ ssh -L54321:serverC:3389 serverB -p 12322 -l yourloginnameonB
```

to create the tunnel.

This command line needs some explanation. Let's do this part by part.

- The -L switch causes SSH to create a tunnel between port 54321 on your client machine, A (notice the prompt) and port 3389 on server C (where I assume the RDP server is running).
- serverB is the name of the machine you "target" with this ssh command. Since you'll be connecting through B, put its full hostname here.
- If your SSH server, B, uses a non-standard port for ssh (as is often recommended for internet-facing machines), put that number here as the -p parameter. In my example, B uses port 12322 for SSH.
- Finally, the -l parameter lets you specify the login name (i.e. your account) to use when logging in to serverB.

If this command succeeds, you'll be able to direct A's RDP client to localhost:54321 and it will feel like you're connecting directly to C:3389.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that your local machine ("A") is a POSIX machine with e. g. OpenSSH, you can do this one of two ways:

You can do it ad-hoc every time you connect with arguments to the SSH client:

```
ssh -L13389:serverC:3389 username@serverB
rdesktop localhost:13389 # Or point any RDP client to localhost:3389
```

Or, for a more permanent setting, you can add the following to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
host serverB
    LocalForward localhost:13389 serverB:3389
```

Then, anytime you ssh to serverB, the tunnel will be open.  One side effect of this, however, is that if you open up several concurrent connections to serverB, you will get warnings that the tunnel is already in-place.